# Filter by column with rows having multiple value using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame as in below and I am filtering by column 'STC' for a value '30'.

I am using below code and I am getting empty data frame. How can I get rows with '30' only?

```
STC = [30]

(df.loc[df['STC'].isin(STC)])
```

```
    Code       Desc     STC    ...  
0  PUT123  Deduct    30,47,57  ...         
1  MAT456   Coins  30, 54, 27  ...         
2  CAT123   Copay   24,27
```

Comment: What is the type of STC? Is it a list of values or a string?

Answer (score 1):

Staged with the assumption that the values in STC are a string of numbers, the example provided does not make them look like lists.

You can use str.contains to find matches.

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict= {'code': ['PUT123', 'MAT456', 'CAT123'], 'Desc': ['Deduct', 'Coin', 'Copay'], 'STC': ['30, 47, 57', '30, 54, 27', '8, 1, 9']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dict)

df2 = (df.loc[df['STC'].str.contains(r'30', na=True)])

print(df2['STC'])
```

Prints

```
0    30, 47, 57
1    30, 54, 27
Name: STC, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark the question as answered if you could.